# Hibernate CriteriaAPI and like operator. Swap operands + database independent concatenation - is it possible?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

**Intro**

I have a weird task - to write on Hibernate Criteria API (i.e. in database independent style) SQL query similar to

```
select * from branch b where '2/5/3/' like b.hier_path + '%'
```

where `+` is concatenation operator. Concatenation operator is database dependent '+' in MS SQL, '||' in Oracle etc.

I must use Criteria API (and no way to switch to HQL).

**Problem #1 - like operator**

Unfortunately, Hibernate allows to write only Criteria based on Java object property:

```
pCriteria.createCriteria(Branch.class).add(Restrictions.like("hierarchyPath", "2/5/3/%"));
```

Which is equivalent of

```
select * from branch where 'hier_path like 2/5/3/%'
```

I don't know how to swap operands of like operator.

**Problem #2 - database independent concatenation**

The SQL code must works on Oracle, MS SQL Server, DB2, Postgres, Sybase, MySQL, HSQLDB, Firebird (and some other new relational databases).

What I've got for now is SQL based hack:

```
Restrictions.sqlRestriction("? like concat({alias}.hier_path,'%')", "2/5/3/", Hibernate.STRING)
```

Unfortunately, `concat` is **database dependent** function that present in most from above mentioned databases (except Postgres and Firebird). The approach is a workaround and could not be used as constant solution (I'll try to add custom functions `concat` to databases that doesn't have it).

**Conclusion**

Could anybody propose an improvement to my hack (a database independent SQL) or correction to original CriteriaAPI?

**UPDATE 28.09.12**

`concat` functions [appears in Postgres 9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)

Comment: I suggest you closely examine the effects of reversing the normal `column like 'string%'` (i.e. `'string' like (column + '%')` and what it asks the database to do.  In your case, any column value beginning with '2' will match (i.e. `2/3/5` _is_ `LIKE '2%'`).  Is this what you really want?

Comment: Yes, I understand all consequences of the SQL. I indeed need it to intersect two hierarchies stored as materialized path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own Criterion implementation, which would generate a SQL clause similar to the one you have in your question, except it would use the dialect associated with the criteria query to get the appropriate concat function and delegate the concatenation to this database-dependant concat function.

Comment: My 2 cents: Dialect doesn't know concatenation operation. It contains hibernate `concat` function that wrap `+` or `||` but the function can't be used in CriteriAPI AFAIK. So I don't see how that approach simplify my life :(

Comment: You get the SQLFunction instance associated with the "concat" HQL function, and call its `render()` method to get the SQL clause allowing to concat arguments for your dialect. That's how the HQL engine makes concat work on all the databases, so I don't see why you couldn't use the same mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @JB Nizet. Code inspired by his ideas:

```
private class InverseLikeExpression extends SimpleExpression{
    private static final String CONST_HQL_FUNCTION_NAME_CONCAT = "concat";
    private static final String CONST_LIKE = " like ";
    private static final String CONST_LIKE_SUFFIX = "'%'";

    private final String propertyName;

    protected InverseLikeExpression(String pPropertyName, Object pValue) {
        super(pPropertyName, pValue, CONST_LIKE);
        propertyName = pPropertyName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toSqlString(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) throws HibernateException {
        String[] columns = criteriaQuery.getColumnsUsingProjection(criteria, propertyName);
        Dialect dialect = criteriaQuery.getFactory().getDialect();
        SQLFunction concatFunction = (SQLFunction) dialect.getFunctions().get(CONST_HQL_FUNCTION_NAME_CONCAT);

        StringBuffer fragment = new StringBuffer();
        if (columns.length>1) fragment.append('(');
        for ( int i=0; i<columns.length; i++ ) {
            String fieldName = concatFunction.render(Arrays.asList(new Object[] {columns[i], CONST_LIKE_SUFFIX}), criteriaQuery.getFactory());
            fragment.append("?").append( getOp() ).append(fieldName);
            if ( i<columns.length-1 ) fragment.append(" and ");
        }
        if (columns.length>1) fragment.append(')');
        return fragment.toString();
    }       
}
```