# Criteria ilike mechanizm

Tags: hibernate

How do I write a custom Creteria API in order to find a unique result,
matching the longest sequence in a database?

If I have the request string "V1234" it should be matched to V123

```
V1234 -> V123
```

If I have the request string "V12XXX" it should be matched to V12

If I have the request string "V" it should be matched to  V

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your values by length desc, and then iterate these values to check whether match, if matched `break`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> values = Arrays.asList("V", "V1", "V12", "V123");
    Collections.sort(values, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o2.compareTo(o1);
        }
    });

    String[] test = new String[]{"V123456", "V127896", "V1877", "V2394"};
    for (String s : test) {
        for (String str : values) {
            if (s.contains(str)) {
                System.out.println(str);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own Criterion implementation similar to `LikeExpression` but with the [operands reversed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12643704/115563). Then to find the longest you have to sort. Unfortunately I don't think you can sort by the length of your field without creating a custom `Order` implementation.

```
criteria.add(new InverseLikeExpression(value, "yourProperty", MatchMode.START)
    .addOrder(OrderByLength.desc("yourProperty"))
    .setMaxResults(1);
```

With HQL this is a bit easier:

```
where :value like yourProperty || '%' order by length(yourProperty) desc
```